# F# Write Mapped Input to Output

Tags: f#

I am new to F# and am starting with a simple project to get going.

I have large txt files that I process - usually about 10 million records.  What I want to do is read the file, filter out some specific rows, map the fields to only take a subset of the columns from the original file, and then output the result.

The 2 questions I have are:

1. How do I filter based on the map.  The file has about 30 fields.
2. How do I take the output of the map and write it to a new TXT file

---

```
//Open the file 
let lines = seq {use r = new StreamReader(kDir + kfName )
     while not r.EndOfStream do yield r.ReadLine() }

//Filter the file
let sFilt = "Detached Houses,Upper Middle"
let out1 = lines 
            |> Seq.filter (fun x -> x.Contains(sFilt)) 

//Write out the filtered file - this works great
//val out1 : seq<string>
File.WriteAllLines("c:\\temp\\out1.txt", out1 )


//Here is where I have an issue
//I am trying to just get 2 of the columns to an output file
//val out2 : seq<string * string>  - this has a different patter than out1
let out2 = out1 |> Seq.map (fun x2 -> x2.Split[|','|]) 
                |> Seq.map (fun x3 -> x3.[0], x3.[3])
```

I get the following error on this line - I know the out1 and out2 are different.  How can I resolve this difference?

Error message:

> Possible overload: `'File.WriteAllLines(path: string, contents: IEnumerable<string>) : unit'`. Type constraint mismatch. The type `seq<string * string>` is not compatible with type `IEnumerable<string>`
>   The type `'string'` does not match the type `'string * string'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is map back to a `seq<string>` from your `seq<string*string>`.

```
Seq.map (fun (str1, str2) -> sprintf "%s, %s" str1 str2)
```

You can just add that to your existing chain of map operations

```
let out2 = 
    out1 
    |> Seq.map (fun x2 -> x2.Split[|','|]) 
    |> Seq.map (fun x3 -> x3.[0], x3.[3])
    |> Seq.map (fun (str1, str2) -> sprintf "%s, %s" str1 str2)
```

Then, once again, you have a sequence of strings which you can write to your file.

Comment: This works perfect.  Thx.

I have read the input file and processed the records I want.  I would like to somehow get the column headings in the file.  The out1 seq had the column names in the first row.  Can I get that and append it?

Answer (score 2):

`fun x3 -> x3.[0], x3.[3]` creates a tuple of strings `string * string`. You need to concat them, e.g. `fun x3 -> sprintf "%s,%s" x3.[0] x3.[3]` (if you want the comma in the output) or just `fun x3 -> x3.[0] + x3.[3]`.

Answer (score 2):

Its also possible that you want to use the CsvProvider if the file is properly structured. No reason for handling any IO if file is properly structured.

Then you get typed data, column names etc "for free"...

If it is not entirely well structured you might also use CsvParser for some less strictness in reading/handling the file.

Take a look at:
https://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/CsvProvider.html
or
https://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/CsvFile.html

Comment: I will look into this.